# How to display bitmap image in background Win32

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, bitmap

I am having a hard time finding out how to load my .bmp image into the background.

Here is my code:

```
wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc; 
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); 
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1)));
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
```

Though the problem is not entirely code related. I simply have a file x.bmp, and I have the IDB_BITMAP1 defined in my resource.rc file and included with an identifier in resource.h -- but when I run it I just get a white screen. The question here is, how can I upload my .bmp image to the .rc file? I am using MSVS20124. When I right click the .rc file add>bitmap>import...>x.bmp I get an error "could not load file". Why is this? I just want to set that x.bmp as the background in my window.

thanks

Comment: What is IDB_BITMAP1 pointing to? If you double click on IDB_BITMAP1 does it show a bitmap? If so, then why do you want to import x.bmp? Open x.bmp in MS Paint & check if it is a valid bmp.

Comment: yea if I double click it, it shows the .bmp that I am linking to it (x.bmp) but when I run the program the background is just plain white.

Comment: Don't set the bitmap as the background brush.  Handle the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message and draw the bitmap onto the supplied `HDC`.  [Drawing a Custom Window Background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162482.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau -- I got it to work thanks to your comment but I added error checking onto the advice of David. Thanks a ton guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not performing any error checking in the call to `LoadBitmap` and the call to `CreatePatternBrush`. Very likely one of these calls fails and so `hbrBackground` is set to `NULL`, which results in a white background.

Your next step is to do some debugging to work out which call fails. Quite likely is that the bitmap file that you are linking as a resource uses a format that is not supported by `LoadBitmap`. Or perhaps the bitmap file is somehow not being linked. But so long as you actually manage to create a bitmap and then a brush, the system will use that brush to paint the background.